# How to load one of same named resources from different jars in a classpath?

Tags: java, spring, jar, embedded-resource

Let's say there is a jar `main.jar` which depends on two other jars - `dep1.jar` and `dep2.jar`. Both dependencies are in a classpath in MANIFEST.MF of `main.jar`. Each of dependency jars has a directory `foo` inside with a file `bar.txt` within:

```
dep1.jar
|
\--foo/
   |
   \--bar.txt

dep2.jar
|
\--foo/
   |
   \--bar.txt
```

Here is a main class of `main.jar`:

```
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new StaticApplicationContext();
        Resource barResource = ctx.getResource("classpath:foo/bar.txt");
    }
}
```

Which of two `bar.txt` files will be loaded? Is there a way to specify in a resource URL a jar the file should be loaded from?

Comment: @Jenson Two _classes_: `bar.txt` is not a class, so there won't be any conflict.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't expect a compile time exception as resource loading is a run time process.

You can't specify which jar the resource will come from in code, and this is a common issue, particularly when someone bundles something like log4j.properties into a jar file.

What you can do is specify the order of jars in your classpath, and it will pick up the resource from the first one in the list. This is tricky in itself as when you are using something like ivy or maven for classpath dependencies, you are not in control of the ordering in the classpath (in the eclipse plugins at any rate).

The only reliable solution is to call the resources something different, or put them in separate packages.

Answer (score 2):

Which one you get is undefined. However, you can use

```
Resource[] barResource = ctx.getResources("classpath*:foo/bar.txt");
```

to get them both (all). The `URL` in the `Resource` will tell you which `jar` they are in (though I don't recommend you start programming based on that information).

Answer (score 1):

Flip a quarter, that's the one you'll get.  Most likely, it will be the one highest alphabetically, so in your case the one inside dep1.jar.  The files both have identical classpaths (foo.Bar), and while this should look to throw a compile time exception, it will not because it will just package both jars up and not try to compile/look at the (this specific file) file as it is a .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

The specification says that the first class/resource on the class path is taken (AFAIK).

However I would try:

```
Dep1Class.class.getResource("/foo/bar.txt");
Dep2Class.class.getResource("/foo/bar.txt");
```

As Class.getResource works cannot take resources from another jar, as opposed to the system class loader.

With a bit of luck, you will not need to play with `ClassLoader`s and hava a different class loader load dep2.jar.

Comment: That's not true, .getResource() called on a class with an absolute path (slash at the beginning) looks at the root of the classpath. The first .jar with the internal structure /foo/bar.txt will be chosen.

Comment: @cobby thanks, that seems to be a misconception I acquired since long ago.  Maybe because of `getClass().getResource("foo.txt")` being dangerous; maybe because of class loaders.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sotirios said, you can get all resources with the same name using `ctx.getResources(...)`, code such as :

```
    ApplicationContext ctx = new StaticApplicationContext();
    Resource[] resources = ctx.getResources("classpath*:/foo/bar.txt");

    for (Resource resource : resources) {

        System.out.println("resource file: " + resource.getURL());

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(resource.getFile());

        if (is == null) {
            System.out.println("resource is null");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    }
```